# scrollHeight and clientHeight are giving the same value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

In main.css the min-height of the body is 5000px,
when i scroll the page the scrollHeight and clientHeight gives me the same value which is (5000),
here is my main.js,
What is the wrong??

```
let el = document.querySelector(".scroller");
let height =
  document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;


console.log(document.documentElement.scrollHeight);
console.log(document.documentElement.clientHeight);
console.log(height);

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  const scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  el.style.width = `${(scrollTop / height) * 100}%`;
});
```

#### [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qom2R.jpg)

please help

Comment: why is this tagged php and laravel?

Comment: what values were you expecting? Can you post HTML and CSS to demonstrate the issue

Comment: the values must changes when i scroll down and up

Comment: * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-height: 5000px;
}
.scroller {
  background-color: #0075ff;
  width: 5px;
  height: 4px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
}

Comment: *in the question* where it's readable

Comment: your code seems to work, what is the issue?

Comment: when i zoom in and out the scrollHeight and clientHeight values must be changed right?

Comment: they are not changing

Comment: Can you put the html, css, js all in the question itself by editing it using Stack Snippets so we can run it? It is of great use.

Comment: What you've shown works as intended. Perhaps something you haven't shown is the issue

Comment: When i tried the code here in code snippets ,it works!! but in VScode it is not, what is wrong??

Comment: I tried to add the code by code snippets but i didnt know how , i am a new member here,you can see the code in this website,  https://elzero.org/tutorials-create-page-scroll-progress/

Comment: I know that the code is correct , but the issue that it is not working in my editor , how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this link: [medium.com/@jbbpatel94/difference-between-offsetheight-clientheight-and-scrollheight-cfea5c196937](https://medium.com/@jbbpatel94/difference-between-offsetheight-clientheight-and-scrollheight-cfea5c196937)

> scrollHeight: The scrollHeight value is equal to the minimum height the element would require in order to fit all the content in the viewport without using a vertical scrollbar.
>
> clientHeight: It includes the element’s padding, but not its border, margin or horizontal scrollbar (if present). It can also include the height of pseudo-elements such as ::before or ::after.
>
> **If the element's content can fit without a need for vertical scrollbar, its scrollHeight is equal toclientHeight.**

[image: Scroll Height]

[image: Client Height]

So, in short, if the whole document doesn't require scrolling or a scroll bar, its scrollHeight is the same has the clientHeight.